# preserve values in text field across the view in ios

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm currently working in contact app I got stuck in between ,when clicked on any name in address book I have various views for adding information in textfield, picker to add date.

Now I need to preserve the values in textfield,table view or switch view etc etc as enter in text field,tableviews and date as it is until and unless user edit once again for various different users in address book....

I'm using nsuserdefault to save the values and to retrieve...

Can anyone pls help me with the logic or with some related code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSUserdefault`. Read up about the Model-View-Contoller (MVC) design pattern. Your problem is exactly what MVC is designed to solve.

Comment: Can you pls provide with any link or resource where this example done .

Comment: These tutorials ar really good: http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns